# Is there any way to prevent user from popping the screen on Flutter web with Router API?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I have a Flutter web app with Router API (go_router) for navigation. As for now, `WillPopScope` widget doesn't work with go_router on the web ([issue tracker is here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102408)). Is there any other way to prevent user from quitting (popping) page (not browser tab) if there are some unsaved changes on the screen?

Maybe it is possible to achieve this with some other Router API navigation package, e.g. auturoute and how?

Comment: as you can see, that issue is still present in go_router and not resolved yet

Comment: yes, but maybe there is some workaround for now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BackButtonListener

```
BackButtonListener(
  onBackButtonPressed: () async {
    print('test');
    return true;
  },
  child: SomeWidgets(),
);
```